# What is the name of the sixth son?

Tags: logical-deduction

Alice's father has six sons.

The first is named Aegon I. The second is named Aegon II. The third, fourth and fifth are named Aegon III, Aegon IV, Aegon V respectively.

What is the name of the sixth son ? (This is not a duplicate.)

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Ohg Nyvpr vf abg n obl'f anzr; Nyvpr pnaabg or gur fvkgu fba.$]$

Comment: @user477343 Y'all [sure about that](http://www.alicecooper.com/)?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I am very sorry for my sexist approach, but I thought the only boy version would be something like *Ellis*. Apologies to the guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be

> Aegon VI

Becuase

> Alice is the daughter and she has six brothers following the pattern 1, 2, ......5, 6.

Answer (score 1):

The intended answer is presumably

> Alice

but there's really insufficient information in the question.

> Maybe it was translated from a language where "sons" also means "children" and so the ambiguity over whether Alice is a son or a daughter was irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe there's a rot13(Genaftraqre) situation going on here?

Comment: @Chowzen Or the father's family name is Cooper? ;-)

Comment: or perhaps Alice is male

Comment: @ClintEastwood, if that's addressed to me then you haven't understood my point in the second spoiler block. Or the answer in the first spoiler block, come to that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the sixth son's name is

> Aegon.

Now let me explain:

> First, I thought that Alice's father just numbers his sons as Aegons from "I" and so on. But if that actually was true, he would name his daughter not Alice, but Alice I. He probably numbers his Alices and Aegons from 'zero' child - thus, the missing son would be his firstborn, Aegon.

Comment: You are right that it would not be logical to name your first son "Aegon I" since you don't know if there will ever be an "Aegon II". But once your first Aegon is born, that would be much less logical to name your second son "Aegon I".

Comment: @xhienne It could be the same thing as with "New Folder", "New Folder(1)", "New Folder(2)" and so on.

Comment: Well, if you start mentioning Windows as a reference for what is logical, everything might become possible ;-) OK, let's say that the father's name is William Gates, then.

Comment: I think that "The first is named Aegon I" is likely contrary to the proposition that there was a first son named Aegon.